# Dictionary Issue Python

Tags: python

**Question:**

> Define the `print_most_common()` function which is passed two parameters, a dictionary containing words and their corresponding frequencies, e.g.,
>
> ```
> {"and":15,  "talon":7,  "frog":1,  "cat":15,  "tests":1,  "dog":2, "bat":14,  "rat":15}
> ```
>
> and, an integer, the number of characters.
>
> The function gets a list of all the words of the required number of characters which are keys of the dictionary and have the highest frequency for words of that length.
>
> The function first prints the string made up of the word length (the second parameter), followed by " letter words: ", then prints a list of all the words of the required length in the dictionary which have the highest frequency followed by the frequency value.  For example, the following code:
>
> ```
> word_frequencies =  {"and":15, "talon":7, "frog":1, "cat":15, "tests":1,  "dog":2, "bat":14, "rat":15}
>
> print_most_common(word_frequencies, 3)
>
> print_most_common(word_frequencies, 4)
>
> print_most_common(word_frequencies, 5)
>
> print_most_common(word_frequencies, 6)
> ```
>
> prints the following three lines:
>
> ```
> 3 letter words: ['and', 'cat', 'rat'] 15
>
> 4 letter words: ['frog'] 1
>
> 5 letter words: ['talon'] 7
>
> 6 letter words: [] 0
> ```

I have attempted the question, and come up with the following code (I realise is not the best way to do this, but we haven't learned python programming in detail yet):

```
def print_most_common(words_dict, word_len): 
    words_list = list(words_dict.keys())
    frequency = 0
    max_word_list = []
    for word in words_list:
        if word_len == len(word) and frequency <= words_dict[word]:
            frequency = words_dict[word]
    for word, value in words_dict.items():
        if value == frequency:
            max_word_list += [word]
    print (word_len, "letter words:", max_word_list, frequency)
```

The issue I am having is that the code works fine for the frequency 3, 5, 6, 0. However, for frequency 4 it is also printing out a 5 letter word:

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
3 letter words: ['and', 'cat', 'rat'] 15
4 letter words: ['frog'] 1
5 letter words: ['talon'] 7
6 letter words: [] 0
```

ACTUAL RESULT:

```
3 letter words: ['and', 'rat', 'cat'] 15
4 letter words: ['tests', 'frog'] 1
5 letter words: ['talon'] 7
6 letter words: [] 0
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
3 letter words: ['and', 'cat', 'pig', 'rat'] 15
4 letter words: ['bird', 'frog'] 7
5 letter words: ['front', 'tests'] 1
```

ACTUAL RESULT:

```
3 letter words: ['and', 'pig', 'rat', 'cat'] 15
4 letter words: ['talons', 'frog', 'bird'] 7
5 letter words: ['tests', 'front'] 1
```

I can't figure out where I have gone wrong in my code.

Comment: Please ignore. I realised I was missing: 'and word_len == len(word):' from the second for statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After figuring out the maximum frequency, you then select *all* words with that frequency, regardless of length:

```
for word, value in words_dict.items():
    if value == frequency:
        max_word_list += [word]
```

You'll need to test the length again:

```
for word, value in words_dict.items():
    if len(word) == word_len and value == frequency:
        max_word_list += [word]
```

You can collect all words for a given frequency and word-length in one go, however:

```
def print_most_common(words_dict, word_len):
    results = []
    max_frequency = 0
    for word, freq in words_dict.items():
        if len(word) != word_len or freq < max_frequency:
            # wrong length or not frequent enough
            continue
        if freq == max_frequency:
            results.append(word)
        else:
            # right word length and *higher* frequency
            max_frequency = freq
            results = [word]
    print (word_len, "letter words:", results, max_frequency)
```

Comment: I tried both ways (mine and what you suggest) but it doesn't seem to work... it gives the right answer but according to coderunner it says it is incorrect. I am not sure what I am missing. Screenshot [link](http://imgur.com/XoJi6hW)

Comment: @Nume: interesting; from that image alone I'd say your output is *exactly the same* as the expected output.

Comment: @Nume: Both your corrected version (adding in the `len(word) == word_len` test) and my version produce that exact output, certainly.

Comment: @Nume: ah, indeed. That's.. unfair, really, because the task description certainly doesn't mention that requirement.

Comment: all our assignments / tasks seem to be like that. Oh well. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Nume: luckily, that's as easily solved as replacing `results` with `sorted(results)` in my function, `sorted(max_word_list)` in yours.

Comment: @Nume: Glad to have been of help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102648/discussion-between-nume-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the word length in the dict loop i.e `and len(word) == word_len`, the frequency might match but the word can be any length as you don't check:

```
for word, value in words_dict.items():
      # make sure the word_len is also equal
      if value == frequency and len(word) == word_len:
          max_word_list.append(word)
```

You can also simply append the word each time, you don't need to wrap the word in a list and extend, the for loop can also be made into a comprehension.

```
max_word_list = [word  for word, value in words_dict.items() if value == frequency and len(word) == word_len]
```

You can also just get the max:

```
def print_most_common(words_dict, word_len):
    mx = max(v for k, v in words_dict.items() if len(k) == word_len)
    max_word_list = [word for word, value in words_dict.items() if value == mx and len(word) == word_len]
    print(word_len, "letter words:", max_word_list, mx)
```